# Copying data within drivers with RtlCopyMemory

Tags: c#, c++, driver, windbg

I have two drivers and C# application. With this app I can write and read values from device. I'm using first driver to pass data from user to second driver, which I'm calling from the first one. Then I'm copying data with `RtlCopyMemory`. Problem is that this function causes *Access Violation* because of null parameter (I'll show where exactly is this happening in code below - I discovered that by debugging with WinDbg). I believe that error is in `DispatchWrite` in one of the drivers.

**First driver**

```
NTSTATUS DispatchWrite (
        IN PDEVICE_OBJECT   pDevObj,
        IN PIRP             pIrp            ) 
{

    #if DBG==1
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_MASK | 0x77, "\n [ FIRST - DispatchWrite ]\n");
    #endif

    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PVOID userBuffer;
    ULONG xferSize;

    PIO_STACK_LOCATION pIrpNext;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION pIrpStack = IoGetNextIrpStackLocation( pIrp );

    IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(pIrp);
    //IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(pIrp);
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION) pDevObj->DeviceExtension;

    status=IoCallDriver(pDevExt->pTargetDeviceObject, pIrp);


    #if DBG==1
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_MASK | 0x77, "\n [ FIRST - DispatchWrite - End ]\n");
    #endif

    return status;
}
```

**Second driver**

```
NTSTATUS DispatchWrite (
        IN PDEVICE_OBJECT   pDevObj,
        IN PIRP             pIrp            ) 
{

    #if DBG==1
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_MASK | 0x77, "\n [ SECOND - DispatchWrite ]\n");
    #endif

    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PVOID userBuffer;
    ULONG xferSize;

    PIO_STACK_LOCATION pIrpStack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation( pIrp );

    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION) pDevObj->DeviceExtension;

    if (pDevExt->deviceBuffer != NULL) 
    {
        ExFreePool(pDevExt->deviceBuffer);
        pDevExt->deviceBuffer = NULL;
        pDevExt->deviceBufferSize = 0;
    }

    xferSize = pIrpStack->Parameters.Write.Length;
    userBuffer = pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer; //this is NULL
    pDevExt->deviceBuffer = ExAllocatePool( PagedPool, xferSize );

    if (pDevExt->deviceBuffer == NULL) 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        xferSize = 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        pDevExt->deviceBufferSize = xferSize;
        RtlCopyMemory( pDevExt->deviceBuffer, userBuffer, xferSize ); //userBuffer is null - access violation
    }

    pIrp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    pIrp->IoStatus.Information = xferSize;
    IoCompleteRequest( pIrp, IO_NO_INCREMENT );

    return status;
}
```

**C# app**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ster ster = new Ster();
            String devPath = "\\\\.\\";
            devPath += textBox1.Text;
            String userMessage = textBox2.Text;
            ster.driverOpen(devPath);
            ster.driverWrite(userMessage);

        }
```

**Ster class:**

```
public Boolean driverOpen(string deviceName)
        {
            this.DriverHandle = CreateFile(deviceName, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
            if (this.DriverHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

unsafe public Boolean driverWrite(string UserMessage)
        {
            uint bW;
            StringBuilder Message = new StringBuilder(UserMessage, 26);

            WriteFile(this.DriverHandle, Message, 26, out bW, 0);
            CloseHandle(this.DriverHandle);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: can you add the code that initiates the Write to the driver?

Comment: Code added. `DispatchWrite` is called by `WriteFile` in `driverWrite`.

Comment: Is `pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer` null when the first driver's `DispatchWrite` is called?  Are both drivers [configured for buffered I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565356(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I don't know, because I have problem with debugging first driver. WinDbg just skips breakpoint like they were not there. I think that I set correct paths for symbols, source and image, but it's not working. 

I have to use direct IO. So maybe they are not correctly configured for this? How do I do that? I must admit that I have problems understanding this from MSDN sites.

Comment: Both set for Direct IO, still same error.

Comment: I've rolled back your code edits, because the code as edited no longer corresponds to the question you were asking.  You can post a new question if you are having difficulty using the MDL.

Comment: Although actually I can see exactly what you're doing wrong: the MDL is *not* the address of the buffer!  It's an opaque structure *describing* the user buffer.  See [Using MDLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565421(v=vs.85).aspx).  In this case, you probably need to start with a call to MmProbeAndLockPages and then I guess MmMapLockedPages.

Comment: On second thoughts, the proper sequence is probably MmProbeAndLockPages, MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe (which returns an address for you to copy to/from) and then MmUnlockPages when you're done.  Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with this stuff!

Comment: I will wait with new one, since now at least I know what I'm looking for, so maybe I'll be able to do it myself. Thanks again for help with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [IRP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550694(v=vs.85).aspx):

> AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer [...]
>
> If the driver is using direct I/O, [...] **NULL**.

And under [IRP_MJ_WRITE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550819(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Input Parameters
>
> [...]
>
> The buffer at Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, **if the driver uses buffered I/O**
>
> The buffer described by the MDL at Irp->MdlAddress, **if the [...] driver uses direct I/O**

(Emphasis mine.)

IoW, the behaviour you describe is exactly as expected.  The `SystemBuffer` parameter is *supposed* to be set to `NULL` when the driver is configured for direct I/O.

You must either reconfigure the driver to use buffered I/O, or use the MDL to access the user buffer.

*NB:* In this scenario, I'm not sure whether it is the configuration of the first or second driver that controls which parameter is passed.

Comment: Thank you! I missed it. Now, after using MDL, I have no errors during debugging. Unfortunately, it's still not working correctly. After reading from device, there's no output. Any idea what is wrong with that? I'll update question right after this comment.